# Undefined Name | Error in TextEditingController (''Flutter/Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Error in "controller" it says undefined name 'profileNameTextEditingController'

language:  Flutter/dart

My Activity :

```
Column createProfileNameTextField(){
return Column(
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
 children: <Widget>[
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13.0),
  child: Text(
    "profile Name", style: TextStyle(color:Color.grey),
   ),
   ])}
```

Comment: Post the code in question please; don't link to .png files. We want the codes! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Pass `profileNameTextEditingController` as argument to `createProfileNameTextFormField` and then use it in controller.

```dart
Column createProfileNameTextFormField(profileNameTextEditingController) {
  return Column(
    ...
    TextField(
      controller: profileNameTextEditingController,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`'profileNameTextEditingController'` scope is only within the class `_editProfileState`.
Just pass controller as argument to the function where its needed.

```
createProfileNameTextFormField(profileNameTextEditingController);
```

```
Column createProfileNameTextFormField(profileNameTextEditingController) {
  
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).